# Step up reactions in elementary organic chemistry

Tags: organic-chemistry

What are some elementary (high school level) step up reactions? (in which the length of the carbon chain of an organic molecule is increased by one)

**Background:** I was looking for a way to methyl chloride to acetone (spoilers: I still haven't found one :( I could use Wurtz reaction to form ethane from methyl chloride, but I don't know of a way to add one more carbon to this alkane. I found [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/23840/organic-chemistry-alkanes-step-up-reaction), but it only focuses on the ketene reagent's action on alkanes. I suppose there might be many more such "step up" reagents and their many more compounds which can be "stepped up". Hence, my question.

---

PS: A term related to "Step up" is "Step down", which observed in Hunsdiecker reaction and Hoffmann Bromamide reaction.

Comment: Cyanide SN2 on halide is a basic one.

Comment: @orthocresol Oh, that's good! You also reminded me of addition of grignard reagent to carbonyl compound.

Comment: In addition to cyanide,dithiane anion or nitromethane anion on halide are possible

Comment: Arndt-Eistert? It's basically high school level reactions in certain order, for stepping up of carboxylic acid